# iOS - QLPreviewController doesn't reload

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have subclassed QLPreviewController and here is what it should do:

QLPreviewController shows photo.
If user want's to change that photo, he can take new one with camera 
(UIImagePickerController is shown)

After that I'd like to show new photo on QLPreviewController but the old photo is still visible.

It seems that QLPreviewItem for the QLPreviewController doesn't change neither on

```
[QLPreviewController  refreshCurrentPreviewItem];
```

or

```
[QLPreviewController reloadData];
```

Proble might be that new photo is saved with same name that old one. (I don't want to change that)

How can I force QLPreviewController to reload that file again?

Comment: What do you mean by: "the old photo is still visible". Are you presenting the preview controller modally or pushing it to a navigation controller?

Comment: I'm showing UIImagePickerController modally on my subclassed QLPreviewController. After UIImagePickerController is done and new photo is saved, I dismiss UIImagePickerController and tell QLPreviewController to refreshCurrentPreviewItem

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving photo with same name as old one in the same directory, there should be the 'File with this name exists' error. Are you deleting old image before saving new one? If not, then you are getting error, and the new image is not being saved on the file system.

Comment: File is properly saved on the system. When I dismiss QLPreviewController, another view shows thumbnails of photos and new photo is shown there.